# Generate random tiled pattern in Starling

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmap, starling-framework

I'm a n00b @ ActionScript3/Starling (both) and want to create a (displayable) object with contents based on a random sampling from a specified pattern.

E.g. assume I have a TextureAtlas having images like:

```
+----+----+----+----+
|  0 |  1 |  2 |  3 |
+----+----+----+----+
|  4 |  5 |  6 |  7 |
+----+----+----+----+
|  8 |  9 |  A |  B |
+----+----+----+----+
|  C |  D |  E |  F |
+----+----+----+----+
```

Actually, the textures are named random0000 to random0015 in the atlas. I'm using for the sake of the question the hexadecimal notation so I can illustrate the problem as follows:

I want to dynamically create a random bitmap from that pattern AND include it inside the starling display context. A random bitmap could be like:

```
234aab9c
346700bf
634bca9e
e349ba23
```

Being in this example a bitmap with 8x4 tiles.

Assume I have a loop like:

```
var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(32 * nwidth, 32 * nheight);
var textures:Vector.<Texture> = myAtlas.getTextures("random"); //random0000 ...
for(var i:uint = 0; i < nwidth; i++) {
    for(var j:uint 0 0; j < nheight; j++) {
        var texture:Texture = textures[Math.round(Math.random() * 16)];
        //???
    }
}
```

1. How do I efficiently dump the texture into the bitmap at (32*i, 32*j) coordinates (bitmap coordinates).
2. Assume I have `var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData)` and a `context` being the starling context: What object (being a starling displayable) could I use to dump the bitmap in, and attach to `context` as a static image as intended? (`context.addChild(???)`).
3. Is safe to change, later, the bitmapData and see the changes in real time in such object?

Thanks, and sorry for the n00b question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1**.You cannot convert a Texture to a BitmapData.  However, you can just use the BitmapData objects that were used for creating the textures in the first place.  With the original bitmaps, you can use the BitmapData.copyPixels() method for dumping the tiled bitmaps into a single bitmap.  You'll need to work with BitmapDatas rather than Textures.  Something like this:

```
var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(32 * nwidth, 32 * nheight);
var textureBitmaps:Vector.<BitmapData> = helperClass.getBitmaps("random");
for(var i:uint = 0; i < nwidth; i++) {
    for(var j:uint = 0; j < nheight; j++) {
        var textureBM:BitmapData = textureBitmaps[Math.floor(Math.random() * textureBitmaps.length)];
        bitmapData.copyPixels(textureBM, new Rectangle(0, 0, 32, 32), new Point(32*i, 32*j));
    }
}
```

You can convert the final bitmapdata to a Texture afterward.

**2**. You could try creating a Texture from the bitmap, and then using that texture in Starling's [Image](https://github.com/Gamua/Starling-Framework/blob/master/starling/src/starling/display/Image.as) class.  That might work, though I'm not 100% sure.

**3**. I don't know the answer to this one.  I didn't find an answer through google either.  You could always just try changing the bitmapdata and see what happens.

Comment: After digging in the source code (could not test it because i'm digging just now) I think that if I keep a reference to the bitmapData passed to the texture in Texture.fromBitmapData, any change to the bitmapData will be reflected - the bitmapData is referenced directly in a closure here: https://github.com/Gamua/Starling-Framework/blob/master/starling/src/starling/textures/Texture.as#L255 (and line 258)